# Adding a cronjob with moodle-cron-api is not working properly

Tags: php, cron, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to schedule a task in moodle-cron-api following the instructions here at: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API.

I have the root folder at /local and the name of the root folder is mod_hygene.

I have a cut_my_toe_nails.php at /local/mod_hygene/classes/task which is:

```
namespace mod_hygene\task;

/**
* An example of a scheduled task.
*/
class cut_my_toe_nails extends \core\task\scheduled_task {

/**
* Return the task's name as shown in admin screens.
*
* @return string
*/
public function get_name() {
return get_string('cutmytoenails', 'mod_hygene');
}

/**
* Execute the task.
*/
public function execute() {
// Apply fungus cream.
// Apply chainsaw.
// Apply olive oil.
echo 'do';
}
}
```

And there is /mod_hygene/db/tasks.php:

```
$tasks = [
[
'classname' => 'mod_hygene\task\cut_my_toe_nails',
'blocking' => 0,
'minute' => '*',
'hour' => '*',
'day' => '*',
'month' => '1,7',
'dayofweek' => '*',
],
];
```

As you see, the task should run every minute. I run my moodle container via terminal with

```
docker-compose up -d --build moodle
```

In the terminal I should see 'do' printed every minute. But, I am not seeing anything. I hovered to Site Administration/Server/Scheduled Tasks. There I am not seeing this task. But I checked in Site Administration/Plugins/Plugins Overview and could find local_mod_hygene in the Local Plugins.

Can anyone help me with it? Do I need to make some changes to the Dockerfile as well?

Comment: This seems rather confused - you have created a 'local' plugin (within the 'local' directory), but you've called this local plugin 'mod_hygene' - i.e. the full name of the plugin will be 'local_mod_hygene'? This is very odd, either it is a local plugin, or it is an activity module (which would be in mod/hygene and called 'mod_hygene'). Assuming you rename the directory from mod_hygene to 'hygene', the namespace for the scheduled task would then be 'local_hygene\task'. I assume you also have a version.php for the plugin?

Comment: @davosmith, I followed https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API. They seem to call it mod_hygene, not local_mod_hygene nor mod/hyegene

Comment: The example given is for an activity module, called mod_hygene, stored in mod/hygene. If you want to create a "local" plugin instead, them you can't name it as an activity module plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tip, don't use the prefix `mod_` for a local plugin, it could be confused for an activity plugin in the `mod` folder.

So assuming your code is in `/local/hygene/`

The task file should be `/local/hygene/classes/task/cut_my_toe_nails.php`

The class namespace should be

```
namespace local_hygene\task;
```

The tasks file should be `/local/hygene/db/tasks.php` with

```
'classname' => 'local_hygene\task\cut_my_toe_nails',
```

Once its installed, check if the task is enabled via

Site admin > Server > Tasks

Or direct to

`yourwebsite/admin/tool/task/scheduledtasks.php`

If its installed and enabled, then run it from the command line to test it.

First see if its listed - if its not listed then its not installed correctly

```
php admin/cli/scheduled_task.php  --list
```

If it it listed, then note the name and run the task manually - note that the `\` has to be escaped with `\\`

```
php admin/cli/scheduled_task.php --execute=\\local_hygene\\task\\cut_my_toe_nails
```

If the task is working correctly, then wait for cron

Or, depending on the settings, you can run cron manually via `yourmoodlewebsite/admin/cron.php` when logged in as an admin

Or from the command line

```
php admin/cli/cron.php
```

Comment: Hey, so I had t change some things (very minute!) from my code to yours but I am glad that it worked! Thanks!